# Spring MVC custom validation annotation with service @Autowired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

I use Spring MVC with Hibernate to develop a Web Application. At first I used only standard JSR303 annotation. Then I decided to use some custom annotation to verify the uniqueness of the username and email of a new User, who would want to create an account.

So I created two annotation like this one (one fr the email and the other for the username) :

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueUsername {

String message() default "{UniqueUsername}";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

And two Validator like this one :

```
public class UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator.class);

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public void initialize(UniqueUsername uu) { }

@Override
public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
    if(username == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return userService.findByUsername(username) == null;
}
```

}

I posted only one because those two are really similar.

The annotation @UniqueUsername and @UniqueEmail work when the email or the username is not unique and send the right message of validation error. But when I give a username and an email not already used, then I have an null pointer error on the userService.

I don't understand why I would have some null problem with the @Autowired annotation. But what is really intriguing me is why the IsValid() method (which give me the null exception) would be called a second time , or at least for m it seems that it' what happen, because the validation step seem to work.

Here is the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.sam.website.custom.validators.UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator.isValid(UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator.java:30)
com.sam.website.custom.validators.UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator.isValid(UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator.java:1)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:153)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:140)
org.hibernate.validator.metadata.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:121)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:327)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:273)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:256)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:210)
org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:136)
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:160)
org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:65)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:62)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:415)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:341)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:258)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:686)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
$Proxy39.merge(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:360)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy41.save(Unknown Source)
com.sam.website.services.jpa.UserServiceJpa.save(UserServiceJpa.java:53)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy46.save(Unknown Source)
com.sam.website.controllers.SecurityController.register(SecurityController.java:63)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Here is my usage of the custom annotation

```
@UniqueUsername
@NotEmpty
@Size(min=3)
@Column(name="username",unique=true)
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
```

And here my configuration

```
    <!-- Validator settings -->
<annotation-driven validator="validator"/>

<beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: How do you create `UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator`?

Comment: I don't create it, I just add my annotation to the username attribute in the user object. I just edited my question and gave the use of UniqueUsername

Comment: I mean where do you declare it? In some spring context? Where does the instance come from?

Comment: No I don't declare it, I followed this tutorial, and it seems that there is no need because it seems to work, at least when the username is not unique. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-custom-validation-annotations.html

Comment: I think that this code must instruct the annotation to call the correct validator : @Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUsernameConstraintValidator.class).  I just add my configuration of the validator.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712345/jsr-303-dependency-injection-and-hibernate

Comment: Thank you it was exactly what I needed, I don't know why I didn't find it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was finally to disable the JPA validation because it was used instead of the Hibernate validation, so the Spring injection wasn't effective. So I just add in my JPA configuration this :

```
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry 
                key="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```