# Spring unit test issue with Validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to write unit test for a validator class that I have. So within my UniqueEmailValidator class, I injected a @Service component to check if it exist.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {
    
    private final AccountService accountService;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(final UniqueEmail constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String email, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !this.accountService.findByEmail(email).isPresent();
    }
}

@Documented
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE}) 
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
public @interface UniqueEmail {
    
    String message() default "{com.x.x.validator.UniqueEmail.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And I tried to write unit test for this constraint validator.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class AccountValidatorTest {
    
    private static Validator validator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;
        
    @Test
    public void shouldDetectDuplicatedEmailAddress() {
        
        User user = new User(); 
        // Setters omit
        
        // accountRepository.save(user);
                        
        Set<ConstraintViolation<AccountRegistrationForm>> violations = validator.validate(user);
        
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }

}
```

How do I initialize the AccountService within the Validator class? It seem like it wasn't injected, hence, the null exception. Here's the trace.

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: com.x.x.validator.UniqueEmailValidator.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.run(ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.getInstance(ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.newInstance(ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.createAndInitializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:533)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:169)
    at com.x.x.AccountValidatorTest.shouldDetectDuplicatedEmailAddress(AccountValidatorTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.x.x.validator.UniqueEmailValidator
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:40)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.x.x.validator.UniqueEmailValidator.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual problem is deep down in the stack-trace that you've provided:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.x.x.validator.UniqueEmailValidator.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
... 52 more
```

This error message is thrown because there is some code that is trying to instantiate the `UniqueEmailValidator` class constructor without any parameters. The problem will be resolved by adding a default constructor to this class:

```
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {
    public UniqueEmailValidator() {
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I have added the first post with the updated stack. Added default constructor doesn't help exactly.

Comment: I don't see the question updated with the updated stacktrace!

Comment: @user1778855, you need to understand that the issue reported earlier is solved and you have encountered a new issue. You may want to accept this answer and ask a new question with your new issue!

Comment: Check your logic, as it is now throwing a `NullPointerException`

Comment: The problem is more than I thought, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764532/how-to-disable-hibernate-validation-in-a-spring-boot-project. It's similar to what I'm facing. However, mine is in unit test. I am still thinking how to apply it for my case in unit test. Thanks though.

Comment: It doesn't answer the problem! @N00bPr0grammer is very shallow and does not address the real problem which is the injection of the service in the Validator.

Comment: @JordanSilva, if you've followed the comments - you'd understand that the question was edited to list down issue after issue. My answer isn't complete, I agree - but only because of what I mentioned earlier!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a default non argument public constructor.
If you need to pass a Spring component into your validator, you may face a problem in test.

I [solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55635585/4587961) by having a component which holds a service and has a static method to give the service.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to setup the test without adding a default constructor by providing your validator as context to the validator factory. You can do this by mocking a `ConstraintValidatorFactory` and returning a new UniqueEmailValidator instance when requested:

```
private static Validator validator;

@Autowired
private final AccountService accountService;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    ConstraintValidatorFactory cvf = mock(ConstraintValidatorFactory.class);
    when(cvf.getInstance(UniqueEmailValidator.class)).thenReturn(new UniqueEmailValidator(accountService));

    validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
        .usingContext()
        .constraintValidatorFactory(cvf)
        .getValidator();
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced basically the same issue but with Mock testing and here's how I solved it:

1. Here is how my custom constraint validation looks like:

Interface:

```
   @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUsernameValidator.class)
   public @interface UniqueUsername {

    String message() default "This username is already in use";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

   }
```

Implementation:

```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

        private final UserRepository repository;

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String username, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            return !repository.existsById(username);
        }
   }
```

2. Annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest`
3. Set up MockMvc through Spring configuration:

   ```
   @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
   @SpringBootTest
   public class RegistrationTest {

       @Autowired
       private WebApplicationContext wac;

       private MockMvc mockMvc;

       @BeforeEach
       void setUp() {
           this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                   .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                   .alwaysDo(print())
                   .build();
       }

       // your tests

   }
   ```