# javax.validator with spring component

Tags: java, bean-validation

I use javax.validation with Spring. In my test (groovy) I explicitly create validator.

```
import javax.validation.Validation
import javax.validation.Validator
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory

ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
Validator validator = factory.getValidator()

when:
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraints = validator.validate(entity)
```

My validator in java

```
public class EntityDynamicValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SomeConstraint, Entity> {

    private GroupService groupService;

    // This constructor is required, see the link bellow.
    public UserDynamicEnumValidator() {
    }

    public UserDynamicEnumValidator(final GroupService groupService) {
        this.groupService = groupService;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Entity entity, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Something something = groupService.findByValue(entity.getValue());
        // Validate all this stuff
    }
}
```

I need to pass a Spring **service** to the validator.

I have a default constructor because there is an issue
[Spring unit test issue with Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104995/spring-unit-test-issue-with-validator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring unit test issue with Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104995/spring-unit-test-issue-with-validator)

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to solve this, however the tests are fully low level unit tests on my side and I wanted to avoid too much of a context. I couldn't even use your approach. The solution my side was to add a custom ConstraintValidatorBean into the mockmvc. That custom implementation could get a list of validator class Class objects and so if the factory tried to create a validator, I returned a Mockito.mock version of it instead of the real one and I could also look that up for expectation settings.

Comment: Also makes sense, thanks for sharing. For unit tests without full context it's a reasonable approach.

Comment: can you please show some example code snippet ?

Comment: @AmolBais sorry, but don't even remember in which codebase I did this :( But I think if you familiar with that class and the original approach described here, then my description should make sense :D

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to share your knowledge. This is how I solved this task.

I created a Spring component and it has a static field (`GroupService` which is initialized in constructor).

```
@Component // Spring component.
class ServiceHolderComponent {
    
    private static GroupService GROUP_SERVICE;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceHolderComponent(final GroupService groupService) {
        GROUP_SERVICE = Validate.notNull(groupService); //apache lib
    }

    public static GroupService getGroupService() {
        return GROUP_SERVICE;
    }
}
```

And now validator with default constructor.

```
public class EntityDynamicValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SomeConstraint, Entity> {

    private GroupService groupService;

    public UserDynamicEnumValidator() {
        this(ServiceHolderComponent.getGroupService());
    }

    public UserDynamicEnumValidator(final GroupService groupService) {
        this.groupService = groupService;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Entity entity, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Something something = groupService.findByValue(entity.getValue());
        // Validate all this stuff
    }
}
```

Apache library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html

`import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: which library you used for `apache` and `Autowired4` ?

Comment: @AmolBais, sorry, not `@Autowired4`, but `@Autowired`. It was a typo. I updated my answer.

Comment: you have my thanks and up vote. nothing better than solving problem at late hour and going bed with a light heart.