# It is possible to disable validation?

Tags: spring, validation

for example I have entity with 20 properties, most of them have validators. Can I somehow disable validators? Ofc I can comment them or just remove but when You have many entities this would take a lot of time and in dev mode I would like to mock dummy data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Hibernate validation in a Spring Boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764532/how-to-disable-hibernate-validation-in-a-spring-boot-project)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property:

`spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`

as stated here:

[How to disable Hibernate validation in a Spring Boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764532/how-to-disable-hibernate-validation-in-a-spring-boot-project)

Comment: What is the related settings for JavaEE project?