# spring boot custom validator runs twice

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, bean-validation

I have a spring boot app with a custom validator that I have created, very similarly to what is described here:

[How to disable Hibernate validation in a Spring Boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764532/how-to-disable-hibernate-validation-in-a-spring-boot-project)

I have tried the suggested solution, which means I added the following line to `application.properties` file:

`spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`

Here's is the code(partial):

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;


@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ReCaptchaResponseValidator.class)
public @interface ReCaptchaResponse {
   String message() default "RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE_INVALID";

   Class<?>[] groups() default {};

   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
 }
```

Then I have:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;


public class ReCaptchaResponseValidator implements 
ConstraintValidator<ReCaptchaResponse, String> {
private boolean status = true;

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    final String secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    System.out.println("Calling isValid with value: " + value);


    try {
        String url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?"
                + "secret=" + secretKey
                + "&response=" + value;

        InputStream res = new URL(url).openStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int cp;

        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }

        String jsonText = sb.toString();

        res.close();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);

        return json.getBoolean("success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Then I have:

```
public class MyModel {
   @ReCaptchaResponse
   private Srting recaptcha;
}
```

I then stopped and recompiled the project, but the validator still runs twice. I don't know why this is happening really, I'm using the latest spring boot version whereas the suggested solution is from 2014...Maybe something has changed since then? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you could share a minimal project which reproduces the issue, that would help

Comment: I am also not sure about that solution (faced myself), so for workaround you could have a separate `Dto` to receive the request and then map it to `Entity`

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea why, but after replacing in my controller `@Valid @RequestBody` with `@Validated @RequestBody` it seems to do the trick, and now the validator runs only once.

Comment: It works! but why?)