# Is it possible to disable automatic validation in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a Spring boot application. My request classes passed to my `@RestController` contains `javax.validation` annotations which I cannot change/remove - they come as a 3rd party library. So I want to validate my request objects manually or don't validate them at all. Unfortunately if I add either:

- `spring-boot-starter-validation` - to have `Validator` bean preconfigured or
- `validation-api` and `hibernate-validator` - to create a `Validator` by myself

Spring automatically enables validation for all my `@RestController`s.

Is it possible to disable automatic validation in Spring?

Comment: could you disable the auto configuration of `ValidationAutoConfiguration`? This can be done with `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ValidationAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Hibernate validation in a Spring Boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764532/how-to-disable-hibernate-validation-in-a-spring-boot-project)

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none