# How to implement Spring-based Bean Validation (JSR-303) constraint validator working in the data access layer?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

For example:

```
public class MyBean {

    @MyValidationAnnotation
    private String whatever;

    ...

}

@Component
public class MyConstraintValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidationAnnotation, String> {

    @Autowired
    private SomeSpringBean whatever;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        ...
        whatever.doSomething()
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Using it in a controller like this works fine:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public String whatever(@RequestBody @Validated MyBean bean) {
        ...
    }

}
```

But in the data access layer it throws NPE:

```
@Autowired
private MyBeanRepository repository;

...

MyBean bean = ...
repository.save(bean); // throws NPE at whatever.doSomething()
```

That is because `MyConstraintValidator` instance was outside of the Spring's container in the second place.

So how to implement and/or configure a validator working well both in a controller and in the data access layer? (I'm using Hibernate + Spring Data JPA for it)

Comment: By correctly configuring your JPA EntityManager to use the same validator factory.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712345/jsr-303-dependency-injection-and-hibernate